# Complete Certificate Request with .p7b file

Tags: ssl-certificate, iis-8, csr, p7b

In IIS 8, I created a Certificate Signing Request. After creation, I can see a certificate in "Certificate Enrollment Requests" in Microsoft Management Console (MMC), as well as the created CSR file. I took the content of the CSR file, and then enrolled with Symantec. After enrollment, a "cert.p7b" file was sent to me. This file contains my certificate, plus intermediate certificate.

At this point, I am not so sure of the correct next step. I know that I need to export out my certificate from "cert.p7b" into a .cer file first.

After that, should I take this exported .cer file, and then do a "Complete Certificate Request" in IIS 8 with it? I notice that when selecting a file in "Complete Certificate Request", the default extension is .cer. Can it take the whole "cert.p7b" file instead?

Instead of doing a "Complete Certificate Request", can I simply just open the exported .cer file, and do a "Install Certificate..."?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `cert.p7b` will contain the final certificate and the certificate chain. A .cer file can contain only one certificate. You need to import all of them. I do not know how to do it in IIS, but you probably need to 'Complete certificate request' because it is needed to match the private key and the public with the returned certificate. If you import the import in a separate way, I'm not sure if Windows will pair it correctly

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I did eventually do a "Complete Certification Request" with the cert.p7b file. It was able to accept the whole .p7b file. Thanks.